# Recursive Query WITH - Parents regardless of levels

Tags: sqlite

I have a simple parent-child table :

```
parent | process
       |
A      | B
A      | C
D      | E
E      | F
F      | G
```

I'd like to create a table who gives every single parent for each process regardless of levels :

```
process | parent_regardless_of_levels
        |
B       | A
C       | A
E       | D
F       | E
F       | D
G       | F
G       | E
G       | D
```

Here is the code i've created to get all parents of a precise process, however, the query replies only one column containing childs of one process, and don't loop over each process. I know that I can't do loop with sqlite.

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  parent_of(process, parent) AS
    (SELECT ID_parent, ID_process FROM dependancies),
  ancestor_of(process) AS
    (SELECT parent FROM parent_of WHERE parent_of.process='process_id'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT parent FROM parent_of JOIN ancestor_of USING(process))
SELECT process FROM ancestor_of
```

Is there a way to use this WITH clause as if it were in a loop, with 'process_id' taking each possible process value ? Thank you by advance.

Comment: Please provide a MRE, ideally in the shape of a `.dump` or as a few lines of `create ...` and `insert ...` . https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Pleasae show the output you currently get.

Comment: Please elaborate the logic of the desired output. I do not get it. Maybe some examples with ".. instead of ... , because ...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this recursive cte:

```
with parent_of as (
  select process, parent from dependencies
  union all
  select p.process,
    (select parent from dependencies where process = p.parent) parent_parent
  from parent_of p
  where parent_parent is not null
)  

select * from parent_of
order by process, parent
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mvWFCLKPDkPLPxoDNexEjN/0).
Results:

```
| process | parent |
| ------- | ------ |
| B       | A      |
| C       | A      |
| E       | D      |
| F       | D      |
| F       | E      |
| G       | D      |
| G       | E      |
| G       | F      |
```